# How to avoid unwanted session carry-over between different instances of an application

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, session-cookies

#### Scenario

I have the local version of a Zend Framework application open in one Chrome tab (development environment). At the same time I have the stage or live version of the same application running on a remote server open as well. I'm logged in one of the instances. When I try to log in to the other, this instance exits with a fatal error until I delete the cookies of the other instance, where I'm logged in first.

The domain setting on the session cookies is not identical but the carry-over still happens.

#### Questions

Why does that happen?
How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each server a different session name (not the default one), so that you have different sessions. This does normally work if you want to use multiple sessions next to each other (and you don't want to check the cookie settings like taking care cookie works in it's domain only and that next to cookie nothing else is used to pass the ID).

In native PHP it's [`session_name`](http://php.net/session_name), I assume Zend Framework has a corresponding configuration setting as well.

Comment: I think this does the trick. The easiest way seems a simple `ini_set('session.name', 'something-project-specific')`. Why does the session name play such a crucial role if the domain param is different?

Comment: If the cookie is shared between the sites (or if session id parameters are used), the session name will be the only thing that can make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

What is the domain setting on the session cookies for both? If it's a top level one, like `.example.com`, then the cookie'll be shared across both systems. You could nail it down to `local.example.com` and `remote.example.com` so the session cookies are distinct and won't overlap.

Comment: The domain is set automatically by Zend_Session and is localhost in one case and subdomain.domain.com in the other case. So it seems this is not causing the problem.