# Pyramid Security - login carries over between separate hosted instances

Tags: python, security, session-cookies, pyramid

I develop and maintain a python pyramid web page. It is deployed live on a separate machine that I have administrative access to (call this Server). I also host it on my own laptop (call this Test).

Login accounts are hashed with bcrypt, such that I cannot read user passwords from the live instance. I can, however, replicate the SQL (I use sqlite) from the live instance to my own Test machine, and do so regularly for testing. I would then replace all hashed passwords with my own password for ease of testing.

Recently I realized that if I'm logged in as user X on my Test instance and then open my Server instance in another tab of the same browser, the Server instance acts as if I'm logged in as user X there.

Is this a security flaw in my web page design? Could it be used to gain access to accounts on the system without knowing their password? [This php question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098861/how-to-avoid-unwanted-session-carry-over-between-different-instances-of-an-appli) says this is linked to the session name I've used for my cookie (and I guess to the secret as well). What are the best security practices for this situation?

Comment: are you used session authentication policy or you used ticket authentication policy? are you used different secrets for each sites?

Comment: It's the exact same site, code wise (well, one obviously gets commits a bit sooner), using session authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the same database on each case (determining what goes into the cookie), and you hash the cookies with the same secret (determining what the outcome of hashing a given payload looks like), then your cookies are interchangeable. This can actually be useful sometimes for multiprocess testing. It's not a security flaw per se, it's by design, but you need to have a separate cookie hashing secret for every deployed instance if you want their cookies not to be usable by each other.

Comment: Thanks, this seems reasonable. Is this a security flaw which is exploitable in some way? Anyone knowing the session secret could pretend to be any user without knowing the user's stored password?

Comment: Nope, that's not a flaw, that's just how cookie based authentication works: the cookie sends data identifying the user session and you encrypt the data with a secret key on the server. Your cookies need a key for the hash, and you need to keep that secret. If you exposed your cookie secret, that would be a security mistake.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your most recent comment I've decided to move the secret out of my source code. Surprisingly, I had not read advise to do that till I actually started searching for information based on your answer....

Comment: Good point. Most frameworks have a comment saying "change this in production" but not "don't check in this to git, yo."

Answer (score 1):

Check if you using the same session secret for development and production environments

Comment: Both environments are identical code wise, so of course the secret is the same.